# not able to see the current branch that I am currently working

Tags: git-bash, bash

I am using git and this is how my bash_profile looks like.

```
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
if [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi   
PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[36m\]\w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
```

I used to see branch_name that I am currently on like this, but it is not displaying any more.
      `project_name(current_branch_name)`

It always displays 
`'-bash: __git_ps1: command not found'`

What could I change in the profile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that git-completion.bash is most likely not at the location you're looking for it.

This means that:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
```

is probably failing.

Try changing this to point at the contrib directory inside your git install dir. For example if git is installed inside /usr/local/git then

```
if [ -f /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ] ; then
    . /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
fi
```